# How to get extra vertical space before group in pgfgantt?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, pgfgantt

Using the `pgfgantt` package, one can uniformly set vertical spacing using the `y unit chart` key. However, i would like to add extra vertical space before certain groups, but the package does not seem to provide for this. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add extra `\\` or `\ganttnewline` wherever you want extra vertical space in the chart.

Please see the manual, p.10, *2.4 Line Breaks between Chart Elements* (`pgfgantt` v4.0).